# Can I add a proprietary library to GPL software?

Tags: gpl-3, proprietary-code

I'm considering developing a project based on a modified version of some GPLv3 code. But, I need to use some proprietary library. This is a for-profit endeavour, in which I plan to sell the modified GPL code with the GPL license to a client and charge for the unitary closed-source cost of the proprietary library, but I cannot change the terms for the proprietary library. I can get license to share the headers or equivalents to them, but surely not to the library itself.

Is that okay? I believe I'd be violating the GPL license terms, but I'm not close-sourcing anything I have access to.

Comment: The profit and selling stuff is not relevant. GPL allows these. However there are other reasons that you can not do it. See below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is that okay?

Almost certainly not.  [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) says in s5c that if you convey (distribute, for the purposes of this answer) modified versions of the original GPLv3 code (which includes distributing larger works incorporating the GPLv3 code)

> You must license **the entire work, as a whole**, under this License to anyone who comes into possession of a copy

Some people make an argument that linking a library into code doesn't create a single work for copyright purposes, but I'm not one of them, and I certainly wouldn't bet a business on being able to do it.

> I believe I'd be violating the GPL license terms, but I'm not close-sourcing anything I have access to.

I agree, but the first part of that sentence matters, and the second doesn't.  As GPLv3 s12 puts it so eloquently:

> If you cannot convey a covered work so as to satisfy simultaneously your obligations under this License and any other pertinent obligations, then as a consequence you may not convey it at all

Comment: And maybe to add: that is the whole point of choosing this copyleft license. Would the authors have wanted to allow the described scenario, they'd have chosen MIT or BSD or similar

Comment: The linking argument depends on the dependencies (not on static vs dynamic vs …). If the modified GPL depends on an incompatibly licenced work, then it is a GPL violation.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm not saying I disagree, but I will note that I made no mention of static vs. dynamic linking.

Comment: @I agree totally with your answer, and comment. I was just pointing out one reason for the disagreement that you mentioned.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thank you for the clarification, for which I am grateful!